# How to set empty value to datafield if contains null in database record?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing project in laravel. I want to return contact from *contact* table. In contact table their is a field named as "city_id". "city_id" can be null.
While fetching record from *contact* table, I want to check whether city_id is null or not and if this fieild is null then instaed of showing null as return value for city_id, I want to set city_id as " " (i.e empty field). I tried using IFNULL but unable to get exact result.

Here is my code:

```
$contacts = ContactList::where('provider_contacts_list_id',$contact_id)->where('is_delete',0)->latest('updated_at')->get( [DB::raw('IFNULL(city_id,"") as city_id')]);
```

but then I get,

```
{
  "city_id": ""
}
```

i.e. only city_id record and not other fileds of contact table because I have added only city_id in get() so if I want other fields of contact as well then I have to specify all that fileds in get() so is their any way to get all contact fields with city_id as ""?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in `Contact` model, for example:

```
public function getCityIdAttribute($value)
{
    return is_null($value) ? " " : $value;
}
```